# Ajax-ing JavaScript variable to Django view getting: AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I am trying to send my JavaScript `this.click` variable from my `.js` file to my Django view `class Click` using Ajax and getting the following error message...

```
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'
```

***Here is my view...***

```
class Clicks(View):
    def post(self, request):
        clicks = request.data.get('clicks')
        return JsonResponse({'status': True})
```

***Here is my .js files ajax...***

```
var image_movement = function(){  //Handles movement of tug of war image
this.total = 18
this.clicks = 0
this.move = function(num){  //Adds or subtracts one from total depending on which player calls it
    if(this.total == 0){
        $('#onewon').show();
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')
            },
            url:  'click',
            type: "POST",
            data: {clicks: this.clicks},
            success:function(response){
                alert("success: " + response);
            },
            error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
                alert("failure: " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            alert("end");
        });
```

***Here is my .js files function for obtaining cookie to give to ajax header...***

```
function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
}
```

***Here is my url...***

```
    url(r'^click$', Clicks.as_view()),
```

***Things that I have tried...***

1) Using `clicks = request.DATA.get('clicks')` instead of `clicks = request.data.get('clicks')` (get the same error as above)

2) Switching to own specific class based view to avoid any interference.

Comment: Hi ea87, Could it be that you access the data like this:  request.POST['clicks']

Comment: @adamteale Hey, that didn't work either. :/

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct terminology but is you Ajax call making it to your Clicks view? Can you print something to test if it gets called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find anything in the Django [Request object docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/) about `request.data`. Is it possible that you mean `request.body`?

On the other hand, Django Rest Framework does add a `data` attribute to the `request` object, but if that's the case - if your using DRF - you should make sure to import `View` from DRF and not from django.